# What is the best icon to show 'randomness' in an Android application?

Tags: android

Currently I am using a clip art image of two dice as a 'random' button:

[image: dice]

However, it doesn't fit the Android look and feel *at all*.

How would I best represent 'randomness' in a button?

Comment: On my android, the music shuffle icon is two forward arrows that cross over. That has a feeling of random. But it is also written Shuffle next to the icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you might want to use a dice icon but with question marks on the faces of it. I have seen it somewhere before.

Something like this maybe.
http://game-icons.net/icons/delapouite/dice/png/perspective-dice-six-faces-random.png

Answer (score 1):

I personally think you nailed it with the dice. If they don't fit, then **play around with them dice** to make them fit.

Or consider these:

[image]

Comment: I had thought of the first image, but that's most commonly used in randomizing the order of songs. If I was shown something like that, I would probably think that that button just changed the order of whatever I was doing.

Comment: What your app is about? And what exactly does this button do? Shuffle things up? like shuffling candies in candy crush?

Comment: I'm making a simple app to view [Cyanide and Happiness](https://explosm.net/comics/) comics. The 'random' button will show a random comic.

Comment: why not the second one? That should serve your purpose!

Comment: Second one looks looks like "refresh" to me.

Comment: That's what he wants to do.

Answer (score 0):

This may be more of a comment than an answer but I can't show pictures in a comment.

The dice say "take a chance" to me, not "Generate random output"

Maybe the shuffle or refresh symbol with a question mark will work?

[image]